# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deployment Error: 502 Bad Gateway - Django Application

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having problems deploying my 1st python django app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The app appears to upload correctly but when I try to use it I get 502 Bad Gateway.

The logs show the following:
***2021/03/25 20:14:53 [error] 5144#0: *357 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.8.43, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "crap-env.eba-2nhwp4ty.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"***

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you ssh to the db instance and verity that it actually works by `curl` it from inside?

Comment: Is there an example of the curl command to use?

Answer (score 1):

Updating based on your comment and the feedback from assembler:

Elastic Beanstalk looks for your config.yml file in the .ebextensions folder

```
~/ebdjango/
|  .ebextensions   <--make sure to include the (.)
|    config.yml
|  ebdjango
|    __init__.py
|    settings.py
|    urls.py
|    wsgi.py
|  db.sqlite3
|  manage.py
|  requirements.txt
```

Also make sure to add your CNAME to the ALLOWED_HOSTS variable in settings.py

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I added the following:  ALLOWED_HOSTS = [crap-env.eba-2nhwp4ty.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com]. I then did an eb deploy which appeared to upload ok. I am using windows10, should the directory containing config.yml have the "." in front of it?

Comment: Are you referring to .ebextensions folder? Yes i think it needs the . in front of it.

Comment: made the change. thank you for the feedback